# Solution book for "Presentations of Groups" by D. L. Johnson

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory

I am recently reading "Presentations of Groups" by D. L JOHNSON  and I am interested in solving  the exercises.

However, there are no solutions to make sure I am on the right track.

Does anyone know if there is a book with the solutions of Johnson's exercises.

Or if you have an idea how I could find similar book with solutions

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such book I am aware of. You could always ask on here if you have any questions or if you wish to confirm your answers.